# How to ignore discrimination column in inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

My system has a customization and they use the same database but the customization has some own tables that the main system does not knows.

I have this Entity in my main system:

```
[Table("WORKFLOW_ITEM")]
public class WORKFLOW_ITEM
{
    public WORKFLOW_ITEM()
    {
        PROJECT = new HashSet<PROJECT>();
        WORKFLOW_HISTORY = new HashSet<WORKFLOW_HISTORY>();
    }

    [Key]
    public long ID_WORKFLOW_ITEM { get; set; }

    public long ID_WORKFLOW { get; set; }

    public virtual WORKFLOW WORKFLOW { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WORKFLOW_HISTORY> WORKFLOW_HISTORY { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PROJECT> PROJECT { get; set; }
}
```

And in my custom system I need to extend to materialize this new collection

```
[Table("WORKFLOW_ITEM")]
public class WORKFLOW_ITEMCUSTOM : WORKFLOW_ITEM
{
    public WORKFLOW_ITEMCUSTOM() 
    {
        ENGINEERING_REQUEST = new HashSet<ENGINEERING_REQUEST>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ENGINEERING_REQUEST> ENGINEERING_REQUEST { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ENGINEERING_REQUEST
{
    [Key]
    public long ID_ENGINEERING_REQUEST { get; set; }

    public long? ID_WORKFLOW_ITEM { get; set; }
    public virtual WORKFLOW_ITEMCUSTOM WORKFLOW_ITEM { get; set; }
}
```

My cotext

```
public class ContextCUSTOM: MyContext
{
    public ContextCUSTOM(string p_ConnectionString) :
        base(p_ConnectionString) { }

    public virtual DbSet<ENGINEERING_REQUEST> ENGINEERING_REQUEST { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<WORKFLOW_ITEMCUSTOM> WORKFLOW_ITEMCUSTOM{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ENGINEERING_REQUEST>()
            .HasOne(ct => ct.WORKFLOW_ITEM)
            .WithMany(ct => ct.ENGINEERING_REQUEST)
            .HasForeignKey(ct => ct.ID_WORKFLOW_ITEM)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

When I try to run a query in this context I receive a runtime error about Discriminator Column but I don't want to use like hierarchy, only composition to add more virtual objects. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible you can try to introduce base class for both `WORKFLOW_ITEM` and `WORKFLOW_ITEMCUSTOM`:

```
public abstract class WORKFLOW_ITEM_BASE
{
    public WORKFLOW_ITEM_BASE()
    {
        PROJECT = new HashSet<PROJECT>();
        WORKFLOW_HISTORY = new HashSet<WORKFLOW_HISTORY>();
    }

    [Key]
    public long ID_WORKFLOW_ITEM { get; set; }

    public long ID_WORKFLOW { get; set; }

    public virtual WORKFLOW WORKFLOW { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WORKFLOW_HISTORY> WORKFLOW_HISTORY { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PROJECT> PROJECT { get; set; }
}

[Table("WORKFLOW_ITEM")]
public class WORKFLOW_ITEM: WORKFLOW_ITEM_BASE {}

[Table("WORKFLOW_ITEM")]
public class WORKFLOW_ITEMCUSTOM : WORKFLOW_ITEM_BASE
{
    public WORKFLOW_ITEMCUSTOM() 
    {
        ENGINEERING_REQUEST = new HashSet<ENGINEERING_REQUEST>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ENGINEERING_REQUEST> ENGINEERING_REQUEST { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not works :(

I received this exception:

" Cannot use table 'WORKFLOW_ITEM' for entity type 'WORKFLOW_ITEMCUSTOM ' since it is being used for entity type 'WORKFLOW_ITEM' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.' "

Comment: @ÉdipoFernandes I missed that you are inheriting context. You will need to do the same with the contexts - move common stuff to a base one.